# VS Code "'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..."

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Flutter.zip (from the official site) for Windows 10 and set up my PATH environment variable.

If I run in command prompt:

```
flutter doctor
```

it runs successfully, but if I run flutter in any IDE's terminal, it displays an error:

> flutter : The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you made sure that this is indeed a flutter project, in which you are running the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check If You added flutter/bin to environment variables path

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcRzF.png)

Comment: Yes i have done it for both system and user variabls  it work in command Prompt but not in IDE's terminal

Comment: I have the same issue to you manage to resolve this? @Faisal

Comment: Add it to the System Path Variable, too. The User Path alone did not work for me on W10. Then restart Visual Code.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal pane, top right, click new powershell and try again. Make sure to add the system path.